# How to change default view of Internal server error in pyramid?

Tags: python, pyramid

I found this in pyramid documentation but is giving import error

```
from pyramid.view import exception_view_config

@exception_view_config()
def internal_error(request):
    response =  Response('Internal error')
    response.status_int = 500
    return response
```

Edit:using python2.7 and pyramid 1.7.2 it gives

```
ImportError: cannot import name exception_view_config
```

Comment: Please consider posting the error message as it will be more helpful to find the issue.

Comment: ImportError: cannot import name exception_view_config

Comment: Can you try reinstalling `Pyramid` using `pip install pyramid --no-cache-dir` because on my machine the code is running fine with the latest `Pyramid`

Comment: i am using python 2.7.11 and pyramid==1.7.2 how to do on that?

Comment: See (https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/install.html) I tested on Python 3.5.2

Answer (score 1):

`exception_view_config` was added in Pyramid 1.8

Answer (score -2):

it seems that you've missed to provide an exception context to `exception_view_config` [as it provided it the example](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/api/view.html?highlight=exception_view_config#pyramid.view.exception_view_config):

```
@exception_view_config(ValueError, renderer='json')
def error_view(request):
    return {'error': str(request.exception)}
```

If you want that view to handle all exceptions then pass `Exception` as a context to `exception_view_config` decorator.